# Comprobar si se ha enviado una imagen por formulario

Tags: php, html, aplicación-web

Tengo un problema que no sé como resolver.
Me gustaría saber cómo puedo comprobar si se ha enviado una imagen a través de un formulario.

Tengo un formulario con diferentes campos, uno de ellos de tipo imagen

```html
<form action="control.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!--Campos de tipo texto -->

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="imagen">Imagen</label>
   <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="imagen" name="imagen" accept="image/*">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="crearProducto">Crear</button>
</div>
</form>
```

En el archivo control.php he intentado comprobar si se ha enviado una imagen de las siguientes formas

```
if(isset($_POST["imagen"])){
    echo "Imagen enviada";
}else{
    echo "imagen no enviada";
}
```

y

```
if(isset($_FILE["imagen"])){
    echo "Imagen enviada";
}else{
    echo "Imagen no enviada";
}
```

pero en ambos casos se ejecuta el else cuando envío la imagen, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esta comprobación?

Comment: Primero debemos saber si se manda, en las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador, tiene una pestaña que se llama network o red, verifica que se esta enviando al momento de lanzar tu formulario.

Comment: Otra que no estoy seguro es si es `$_FILE`o `$_FILES`

Comment: Cambia esa parte donde pones $FILE['imagen'] por $FILES['imagen']

Comment: Es $FILES, pues esto es un array de tipo global que puede guardar varios registros de las imagenes que subas, si es que subes mas de una por ejemplo

Comment: @elporfirio he probado con $_FILES pero se ejecuta siempre el If, independientemente de si se ha enviado imagen o no

Comment: @SoniaToledo he probado con $_FILES pero se ejecuta siempre el If, independientemente de si se ha enviado imagen o no

Comment: No se si ya lo has solucionado pero queria comentar que la variable $_FILES puede ayudarte a saber cual es el error, $_FILES['imagen']['error'] accediendo asi, esto debe darte un numero, que es el codigo de error. Puedes ver en la documentacion de php para mas detalles:  http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

if(isset($_FILES["imagen"])){
        echo "Imagen enviada";
   //ademas puedes probar
   print_r($_FILES["imagen"]); // te mostrara la informacion sobre el archivo enviado 
}
else{
   echo "Imagen no enviada";
}

Esta es la forma correcta de recibir un archivo desde el formulario

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisa [answer] para realizar buenas respuestas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

`$nombre_imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
if($nombre_imagen!=""){
    echo "Imagen enviada";
}else{
    echo "Imagen no enviada";
}`